# /can you install ubuntu to hdd but it runs completely from ram while hdd is not spinning?

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, battery, ram

my main purpose is to be able to install ubuntu to the hard disc so that my settings and everything are saved but i want it to load itself to my  ram for faster operation and better battery life while the hdd sleeps

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! How do you think this is feasible? Whenever you save data it will be written to RAM only - or wake up your disk. Please explain why (or how) you think this is possible to do this without loosing all your data. And actually, the Live CD/image is already running like this. It's a SquashFS filesystem in memory with the ability to write into it (in memory), but you'll loose all changes when you turn your PC off.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1594694

It is a lengthy how-to on the forums ;)

It will use the hard disk (or flash drive) if you wish to save your data between boots.